# Repeating mean estimation by groups on each column individually

Tags: r, group-by

I would like to estimate the weighted mean for 47-factor variables by level (5 levels). I would like to do this separately for each variable. The 47 variables of interest are called skill_1, skill_2....skill_47

I know how to do this for one column:

```
earning<-group_by(mydata, skill_1)

earning_by<-summarise(earning, earw=weighted.mean(ear, weight, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The result I get is as follows ( earning by 5 levels of skills_1)

```
skill_1     earw
   <dbl>    <dbl>
1      1   22568.
2      2   21813.
3      3   20361.
4      4   19219.
5      5   14121.
```

But I do not know how it can be done for all 47 variables individually. I would rather avoid doing it 47 times.

I have tried group_by_at :

```
earning<-group_by_at(mydata, .vars = vars(153:200))
```

but it does not work in my case it groups all the variables together.

I have also tried to write a loop as in fact I want to repeat the same operation 47 times but I was not successful.

Many thanks!

Comment: what is your desired output? it's not quite clear how you want to combine this grouped results

Comment: I'd suggest you post a small representative dataset as an example. Let's say 10 rows, but you don't need to post all 47 variables. Post only `skill_1`, `skill_2`, `ear` and `weight`. And also your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `gather` and `spread`:

```
mydata <- tibble(skill_1 = sample(1:5, 100, replace=T),
                 skill_2 = sample(1:5, 100, replace=T), 
                 skill_3= sample(1:5, 100, replace=T), 
                 ear = runif(100, 0, 1))

  mydata %>% 
      gather("key", "value", contains("skill")) %>% 
      group_by(key, value) %>% 
      summarise(mean = mean(ear)) %>% 
      spread("key", "mean")
```

Comment: Dear Thijs, thank you so much. The gather and spread approach was exactly what I was looking for. I should have thought about it myself-:)